# I cannot call method even though I defined it in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller

```
<% @links.each do |link|  %>

   <p class="source list-group-item"><%= link_to 'Plz', songs_path, 
method: :current_user.save_link(link), data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></p>

<% end %>
```

I tried to activate the method but getting error saying there is no such a method.

Here is my controller code.

```
def self.save_link(linkurl)
        @current_user = current_user.artist_url 
        @current_user= linkurl
        @current_user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
        redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Which method are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying a `method` on a link, doesn't do what you're expecting it to do because that's not how you specify which *controller* method is going to be executed. The `method` is the *request type*. To hit a controller method from a link like this, you need to create a route to it and use it as your path.

routes.rb

```
patch '/save_link', to: 'controller#save_link'
```

We set the method to `:patch` here because you're *updating* information. You could also use `:post` if you wanted, but `:patch` is probably closer to best practice here.

```
<%= link_to 'Plz', save_link_path(link: link), method: :patch, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

Your method should also look like this

```
def save_link
  @current_user = current_user.artist_url 
  @current_user = params[:link]
  @current_user.save
  flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Check out the documentation on rails routing here for more information: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web

Comment: I still got the error for the method. for here @current_user.save They say it is undefined method...

Comment: That's a different problem @nisino25. And it's clearly because you're defining `@current_user` to `current_user.artist_url `, which doesn't make sense. Advice, open a new question explaining carefully this problem, what you're doing and what you're expecting to do.